# Geocoder class is not working properly in android

Tags: android

My application I'm using Geocoder class for retrieve the location latitude and longtude

My code is :

```
addressInput = street+","+city+","+pin+","+country; 
List<Address> foundAdresses = gc.getFromLocationName(addressInput, 5);
```

First time it is throwing exception like this

> java.io.IOException:Unable to parse response from server
>
> ERROR/ProtoRequestListener(566): com.google.common.async.WatchdogException

Plese resolve it and if you have any code retrieve the location latitude and longitude send me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should solve your problem.

```
List<Address> addresses = 
          new Geocoder(this,Locale.getDefault()).getFromLocation(lat, lon, 1);
```